# Python3 handling non-ASCII characters in a weird way

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode, ascii, non-ascii-characters

I was trying to solve a pwnable with Python 3. For that I need to print some characters that are not in the ASCII range.

Python 3 is converting these characters into some weird Unicode.

For example if I print `"\xff"` in Python 3, I get this:

```
root@kali:~# python3 -c 'print("\xff")' | xxd
00000000: c3bf 0a                                  ...
```

`\xff` gets converted to `\xc3\xbf`

But in Python 2 it works as expected, like this:

```
root@kali:~# python -c 'print("\xff")' | xxd
00000000: ff0a                                     ..
```

So how can print it like that in Python 3?

Comment: Please post the code here instead of an image

Comment: root@kali:~# python3 -c 'print("\xff")' | xxd  
00000000: c3bf 0a                                  ...  
root@kali:~# python -c 'print("\xff")' | xxd  
00000000: ff0a

Comment: In the question please!

Comment: done, added it.

Comment: Good job being responsive

Comment: What is `xxd` command ?

Comment: not sure is it hex dump?

Comment: Well I pipe out the stdout from python to the stdin in the xxd command which converts it into hex.

Comment: yes its a hex dump

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Python 2, `print '\xff'` writes a bytes string directly to the terminal, so you get the byte you print.

In Python 3, `print('\xff')` encodes the Unicode character U+00FF to the terminal using the default encoding...in your case UTF-8.

To directly output bytes to the terminal in Python 3 you can't use `print`, but you can use the following to skip encoding and write a byte string:

```
python3 -c "import sys; sys.stdout.buffer.write(b'\xff')"
```

Answer (score 3):

In Python 2, `str` and `bytes` were the same thing, so when you wrote `'\xff'`, the result contained the actual byte `0xFF`.

In Python 3, `str` is closer to Python 2's `unicode` object, and is not an alias for `bytes`. `\xff` is no longer a request to insert a byte, but rather a request to insert a Unicode character whose code can be represented in 8 bits. The string is printed with your default encoding (probably UTF-8), in which character 0xFF is encoded as the bytes `\xc3\xbf`. `\x` is basically the one-byte version of `\u` when it appears in a string. It's still the same thing as before when it appears in a `bytes` though.

Now for a solution. If you just want some bytes, do

```
b'\xff'
```

That will work the same as in Python 2. You can write these bytes to a binary file, but you can't then print directly, since everything you print gets converted to `str`. The problem with printing is that everything gets encoded in text mode. Luckily, [`sys.stdout`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.stdout) has a `buffer` attribute that lets you output `bytes` directly:

```
sys.stdout.buffer.write(b'\xff\n')
```

This will only work if you don't replace `sys.stdout` with something fancy that doesn't have a `buffer`.

Comment: That gives me AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'encode'

Comment: That still gives me the exact same output as print("\xff")

Comment: root@kali:~# python3 -c "print(b'\xff'.decode('latin-1'))" |xxd
00000000: c3bf 0a                                  ...

Comment: Yeah. I just realized what I did. It still prints in utf-8. Hang on a sec

Comment: @3xpl017. Fixed

Comment: This answer explains that the raw bytes are the same in Python 2 and 3 but printing makes them strings with different encoding